# Problem related to the discrete logarithm problem

Tags: discrete-logarithm, hardness-assumptions

Let $G$ be a generator of a cyclic group in which the discrete logarithm problem is hard and $x$ and $u$ be scalars of the group such that $X = xG$ and $U = uG$, respectively. We want to compute $J = x^{-1}U$. Is it possible to calculate it without knowing $x$, even if we know $u$?

Comment: Usually one can prove this by reducing the problem into Dlog. What is the source of this problem? What did you try?

Comment: Which one, $U$ or $X$? It is used as a linking tag in a linkable ring signature, for example. Do you want a reference? I tried many things, thats why I am asking here :p

Comment: Where did you see this problem, homework, exercise, article, while doing research, etc? You should indicate it, right?

Comment: I saw it here: https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/018. Basically, I need to forge $J$ without knowing the secret key $x$ for a security proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is equivalent to the Computational Diffie Hellman problem; this remains true even if we know $u$.

See [this paper](http://pdf.aminer.org/000/314/734/variations_of_diffie_hellman_problem.pdf) for details; in summary:

- Suppose we have an oracle that, given $G$, $X = xG$ and either (depending on the oracle type) $U = uG$ or $u$, gives us the value $J = x^{-1}uG$.  Then, we can use this Oracle to construct a second Oracle that, given $H, aH$, computes $a^2H$ (by passing $G = aH$, $X = H = a^{-1}G$, $U=G$ (or $u=1$), and recovering $J = (a^{-1})^{-1} \cdot 1 \cdot aH = a^2H$.  We can then use this second Oracle to solve the CDH problem (given $G, aG, bG$, we compute $(2ab)G = (a+b)^2G - a^2G - b^G$, and then do a point halving.
- Suppose we have an oracle that solves the CDH problem, that is, given $H, aH, bH$, gives us the value $abH$.  Then, given $G$, $xG$, we can compute $x^{-1}G$ by setting $H = xG$, $aH = bH = G = x^{-1}H$ and $bH = H$.  We give this to the Oracle which gives us the value $(x^{-1} \cdot x^{-1}) H = x^{-1}G$.  Then, we can convert that value into $J$ by either multiplying it by $u$ (if we know it), or invoking our CDH Oracle one more time with the inputs $G, x^{-1}G, uG$.

Comment: Thank you, @poncho! So there is no way to construct an oracle that computes $J$ without knowing $x$, right? I needed that for a security proof...

Comment: @Fiono: actually, if you can solve the CDH problem without solving the DLog problem, you can compute $J$ without knowing $x$

Comment: but can you? I mean, aren't the two considered equally hard problems? If you can solve one, can't you solve the other by some kind of reduction?

Comment: @Fiono: there is no known generic reduction from the DLog problem to the CDH problem.  Of course, we can reduce the CDH problem to the DLog problem; if you have a DLog oracle, you can solve CDH in the fairly obvious way...

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!